# Matlab: How to replace certain elements of a matrix A by other values of A in both directions?

Tags: matlab

for a matrix A (10x100000) containing numbers between 1 and 100, how to interchange some elements of A by other values ​​of A in both directions?

example:

replace numbers [5 7 9 18 55 4] by [47 78 41 1 99 98] and [47 78 41 1 99 98] by [5 7 9 18 55 4]

Comment: The first condition says "replace each 4 by a 98", whereas the second says "replace each 4 by a 9". They seem to be contradictory.

Comment: this is just an example, it's true I made ​​a mistake!

Comment: Check my answer and example. I think it does what you need

Comment: So we replace 5 by 47 with the first step and then in next step we replaced the already replaced 47 by 5 or the original 47 by 5? My solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24620689/3293881) assumes the latter, because the former one won't do anything in the big picture.

Answer (score 3):

Use the two outputs of [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
n1 = [1 2 3]; %// first set of numbers
n2 = [4 5 6]; %// second set of numbers
[v1, i1] = ismember(A,n1);
[v2, i2] = ismember(A,n2);
A(v1) = n2(i1(v1));
A(v2) = n1(i2(v2));
```

Example:

```
>> A = randi(8,4,5)
A =
     2     2     8     4     6
     2     5     3     8     2
     5     4     3     2     5
     4     3     2     3     4
```

is transformed into

```
A =
     5     5     8     1     3
     5     2     6     8     5
     2     1     6     5     2
     1     6     5     6     1
```

Answer (score 1):

**[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** based approach -

```
%// Input matrix
A = randi(100,10,10)

vec1 = [5 7 9 18 55 4 , 47 78 41 1 99 98]; %// Numbers to be replaced
vec2 = [47 78 4 1 99 98, 5 7 9 18 55 4]; %// Numbers to be used as replacements

[v1,v2] = max(bsxfun(@eq,A(:),vec1),[],2);
A(find(v1)) = vec2(v2(v1))
```

Sample run -

Input A

```
A =
    27    37    27    59    37    13    55    45    29    16
    84    41    58    46    75    39    75    51    49    16
   100    37    88    87    71    82    85    54    69    16
    65    47     7    67    71    99    17    86    21     9
    71    51    45    36     1    87    91    68    61    46
    94    92     9    35    38     9    11    81    33    67
    69    21    57    26    91    34    75    54    89    84
    57    34    54    96    32    24    73    96    14    80
    39    58    77    30    60    32    72     7    11    72
    64    49    24    16    30    99    14    55    96    48
```

Output A

```
A =
    27    37    27    59    37    13    99    45    29    16
    84     9    58    46    75    39    75    51    49    16
   100    37    88    87    71    82    85    54    69    16
    65     5    78    67    71    55    17    86    21     4
    71    51    45    36    18    87    91    68    61    46
    94    92     4    35    38     4    11    81    33    67
    69    21    57    26    91    34    75    54    89    84
    57    34    54    96    32    24    73    96    14    80
    39    58    77    30    60    32    72    78    11    72
    64    49    24    16    30    55    14    99    96    48
```

As can be seen, the `7s` from (4,3) and (9,8) in the original `A` are replaced by `78s` and `47` in (4,2) by `5`.

Comment: Does this work in both directions (as the OP wants)?

Comment: @LuisMendo Finally it does with the lifesaver `bsxfun`! :) Well  with `intersect` it was only detecting the first matches.

Comment: `bsxfun`... now it's much more like you :-) Still, the numbers of the second set are not replaced by those in the first. For example, 98 doesn't become 4

Comment: @LuisMendo Guess that's not clear to me, so posted a query for OP.

Comment: @LuisMendo Hopefully this is what OP wants after the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is a strange and mysterious place. Searching through the documentation I found a function called [changem](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/changem.html) in the Mapping toolbox. I've never used it, but apparently if you have your original matrix `A` and two substitution vectors `v1 and v2`:

```
v1 = [ 5  7  9 18 55  4];
v2 = [47 78 41  1 99 98];
```

All you have to do is:

```
B = changem(A, [v1 v2], [v2 v1]);
```