# Fill cell array with elements based on the indices MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a n*m cell array Cell_In:

```
a b
* *
* *
c *
* d
* *
* f
```

* --> represents empty string (''). Here is what I need:

```
a b
a b
a b
c b
c d
c d
c f
```

For a particular column I need to fill the empty cell with the previous non-empty cell until another non-empty cell is found. Following is the code what I wrote.

```
b = ~cellfun(@isempty,a);
c = [find(b(:,1) == 1);size(a,1)+1]; e = diff(c);
d = [find(b(:,2) == 1);size(a,1)+1]; f = diff(d);
s1 = ''; s2 = '';
for i = 1:length(e)
    s1 = [s1,repmat(a(c(i),1),1,e(i))];
end

for i = 1:length(f)
    s2 = [s2,repmat(a(d(i),2),1,f(i))];
end
Cell_Out = [s1',s2'];
```

It's working fine but I want to know the best solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `A` to be the input cell array, there could be two approaches here.

**Approach #1**

```
%// Initlialize output array
Aout = cell(size(A));

for k = 1:size(A,2)

    %// Select one column
    Ak = A(:,k);

    %// Logical array with size of Ak and ones at places with non-empty strings
    pos = cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(x), Ak);

    %// Find unique strings and find indices for all places in that column
    %// with respect to those unique strings
    [unq_str,~,str_idx] = unique(Ak,'stable');

    %// Perform cumsum on pos to get an array with a "stepped" array that
    %// steps up at each non-empty string position.
    %// Then replace each stepping number with the string IDs
    idx = changem(cumsum(pos),str_idx(pos),1:sum(pos));

    %// Index into each column with those replaced IDs for the final output
    Aout(:,k) = unq_str(idx);
end
```

With the input slightly changed for testing out the solution code a bit more aggressively, we had after code run -

```
A = 
    'a'    'b'
    ''     '' 
    ''     'a'
    'c'    '' 
    ''     'd'
    'a'    '' 
    ''     'f'
    'c'    'a'

Aout = 
    'a'    'b'
    'a'    'b'
    'a'    'a'
    'c'    'a'
    'c'    'd'
    'a'    'd'
    'a'    'f'
    'c'    'a'
```

---

**Approach #2 [Compact and maybe more efficient]**

You can reshape the input cell array into a single columned cell array and as such you won't need to loop through the columns of
the cell array and this could lead to a more efficient and compact code -

```
%// Reshape all cells into a single columned cell array
A1 = A(:);

%// Rest of the code borrowed from previous approach with reshaping added
%// at the end to bring the output back to the size of input array
pos = ~cellfun('isempty', A1);
[unq_str,~,str_idx] = unique(A1,'stable');
Aout =  reshape(unq_str(changem(cumsum(pos),str_idx(pos),1:sum(pos))),size(A));
```

---

**Bonus: Customized implementation of `changem`**

The codes listed earlier uses **[`changem`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/changem.html)** that needs **`Mapping Toolbox`**. So, if you do have it, here's a customized version of it, implemented with `bsxfun` and `max` and is merely a polished version of an earlier solution code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620302/matlab-how-to-replace-certain-elements-of-a-matrix-a-by-other-values-of-a-in-bo/24620689#24620689). Here goes the custom function code -

```
%// CHANGEM_CUSTOM  Home-cooked vesion of CHANGEM with MAX, BSXFUN
function A  = changem_custom(A,newvals,oldvals)

[valid,id] = max(bsxfun(@eq,A(:),oldvals(:).'),[],2); %//'
A(valid) = newvals(id(valid));

return;
```

So, to use this custom function to replace `changem`, just replace the function call name there in the earlier codes.

Comment: Exellent. Thank you for the solutions. Today I learnt new function "changem".

Comment: @nik Yeah! In fact I saw it just once before, so its pretty new to me too!

Comment: Wow! `changem`!  Cool!  If I wanted to replace multiple entries in a matrix, I'd always loop it with logical indexing.  So glad to learn that there is a convenience function out there.  +1

Comment: @rayryeng There are few alternatives to avoid looping in such cases, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620302/matlab-how-to-replace-certain-elements-of-a-matrix-a-by-other-values-of-a-in-bo).

Comment: @Divakar What about if there is no Mapping Toolbox? Any ideas.

Comment: @nik In that case, you can use the codes from [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24620689/3293881)

Comment: @Divakar I tried hard and still I couldn't get the desired result. Would you please help?

Comment: @nik Check out the just added Bonus section :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution gets the indices of empty cells and fills it with the data from the previous one. To fill larger gaps multiple steps are required.

```
ix=find(cellfun(@isempty,M))
while numel(ix)>0, M(ix)=M(ix-1);ix=find(cellfun(@isempty,M)); end
```